# For websites built with LAMP, can PHP start Node.js or Python tasks and respond to network requests?

Tags: lamp

I have a website that used to be Linux+Apache+MySQL+PHP, but there are many required functions on GitHub which are written in Node.js or Python, and the version written in PHP is missing.

I found that network requests through port `80` are handled by Apache by default through PHP.

So I want to ask, how to start a Node.js or Python task on a website built by LAMP to respond to network requests?

I personally haven't learned Node.js or Python, so I don't know anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your Node.js and Python applications are both web applications, then after startup, they should be listening on a port locally to handle HTTP requests, then you have 2 options .

1. Use the proxy function of Apache or Nginx to forward requests under a specific path to the port that the corresponding Node.js or Python listens to.
2. In PHP, directly use `curl` or `file_get_content` request listening port, that is, implement a proxy at the code level, so that you can also access the Node.js or Python application behind .

If your Node.js and Python application is not a web application, but a command line tool, then this is a relatively common situation, in which case you can use `php` like: `exec`, `shell_exec`, `system` or `Symfony/Process`, `FFI` These methods directly use PHP to execute these commands, just like you execute these commands on terminal (may require a full executable file path, and care about permissions, after all, when you execute it directly, there are relevant environment variables, and when PHP is executed, it is on the `www` or `apache` user). It is necessary to pay attention to command security issues to avoid splicing unsafe commands for execution, which will cause security problems.